# gevents: 'TypeError: a float is required' error message when downloading files

Tags: python, gevent

I'm trying to use gevents to download some images from the web. The images download but I get the following error which arrises when I'm joining the jobs.

```
pool.join(jobs)
TypeError: a float is required
```

The images do download but I don't think I'm threading them correctly ... Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong..?

```
pool = Pool(3)
N = 3

urls = ['http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg', 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg,'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg']

finished = 0

def download_file(url):
    global finished

    print('starting %s' % url)
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10000)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print 'e : ' % e
    else:
        data = data.read()
        filename = os.path.basename(url)
        f = open(filename, 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
    finally:
        finished += 1

with gevent.Timeout(10000000, False):
    for x in xrange(10, 10 + N):
        jobs = [pool.spawn(download_file, url) for url in urls]
        pool.join(jobs)

print('Finished %s' % (finished, N))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pool.join(jobs)
TypeError: a float is required
```

It needs a float and you are passing another type.

Try printing `jobs` to see exactly  what type it is.

```
print(jobs, type(jobs)) should help you see what is happening.
```

You are also missing a `'` around one of your urls  in your list of urls.

According to the [docs](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html#gevent.pool.Group.join), join takes the following args, `join(timeout=None, raise_error=False)`.

If you remove  `join` the code runs, you need to check out the docs to see what you need.

Your string formatting is also incorrect, you have two args to format but you only have one `%s`.

You can use `print('Finished {0} {1}'.format(finished, N))`